# How to transfer data from a View to a Controller then to another View (MVC C#)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, razor, model-view-controller

I am making a bank web app. I have a BankView in which I am able to add new users to a table. I am able to do this by opening an AddUserView and transferring the data from TextBoxes to the controller and then passing this information back to the BankView using a model. Now in the bank view, next to each users name there is a ViewUser Button that allows you to view the user by transferring you to a strongly typed ViewUser View. My issue is how to get the specific user from the table and transfer this data to the Controller so I can then go to the ViewUser View and view more information about the user, i.e account information

I have tried many "solutions" from the internet, for example, I tried using the ViewModel to transfer data from the BankView to the ViewUser View but in all the examples, Textboxes were used but im trying to send data making use of paragraphs instead of textboxes because I do not want the user to be able to change information about the User from the BankView

This is my Bank Controller

```
    public class BankController : Controller
    {
        //Global Variables
        public static List<UserViewModel> Users = new List<UserViewModel>();
        public static VaultViewModel VaultData = new VaultViewModel();
        public static BankViewModel BankData = new BankViewModel("Absa" , Users , VaultData);

        // GET: Bank
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Bank()
        {

            VaultData.Amount = 3500000;
            BankData.lsUsers = GenerateTestDataUsers();

            return View(BankData);
        }
        public ActionResult AddUser()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddUser(string Name , string Surname)
        {

            UserViewModel NewUser = new UserViewModel(Name, Surname);
            BankData.lsUsers.Add(NewUser);

            return View("Bank", new BankViewModel("Absa", BankData.lsUsers, VaultData));
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ViewUser(UserViewModel User)
        {

            string UserName = User.UserName;
            string UserSurname = User.UserSurname;

            return View(User);

        }

        //Methods
        private List<UserViewModel> GenerateTestDataUsers()
        {

            UserViewModel User1 = new UserViewModel("Shanah", "Suping");
            UserViewModel User2 = new UserViewModel("Jackson", "Parker");
            UserViewModel User3 = new UserViewModel("Jacqueline", "Rover");
            UserViewModel User4 = new UserViewModel("Cho", "Chan");
            UserViewModel User5 = new UserViewModel("Rendani", "Rambuda");

            Users.Add(User1);
            Users.Add(User2);
            Users.Add(User3);
            Users.Add(User4);
            Users.Add(User5);

            return (Users);

        }

    }
```

This is my BankView

```
<div id="BankInfo">

    <h1>@Model.BankName</h1>
    <h2>Vault Total: R @Model.Vault.Amount</h2>




    <table>

        <tr>
            <th colspan="4" id="HeadUser">Users <span>@Html.ActionLink("+", "AddUser", "Bank")</span> </th>
        </tr>

        <tr>

            <th>UserID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th></th>

        </tr>

        @foreach (var User in Model.lsUsers)
        {

            <tr>
                <td>@User.UserID</td>
                <td>@User.UserName</td>
                <td>@User.UserSurname</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.BeginForm("ViewUser", "Bank", FormMethod.Post)
                    {
                    <input type="submit" value="View" id="ViewUser" name="ViewUser" />
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>

        }




    </table>

</div>
```

Just a final clarification. I am trying to get the specific user to the BankController so that I can view THAT users information to the ViewUserView.

I expect to be able to obtain the specific user from the BankView and transfer that User to the ViewUser View. But whats actually happening is nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is, change in your bank view inside foreach loop. You could just pass the id of the user and get details on Controllers logic and display on the view.

```
@foreach (var User in Model.lsUsers)
{

    <tr>
        <td>@User.UserID</td>
        <td>@User.UserName</td>
        <td>@User.UserSurname</td>
         <td>@Html.ActionLink("ViewUser", "ViewUser", new { id = @User.UserID }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })</td>
    </tr>

}
```

Now modify your Action Method Like below.

```
    [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ViewUser(string id)
        {
            UserViewModel User = GenerateTestDataUsers().Find(x => x.UserID == id);     
//In real life application you will be calling data service or entityframework

            return View(User);

        }
```

And Your View of View User will be like below.

```
@model UserViewModel


<h2>ViewUser</h2>

<div>
    <h4>UserViewModel</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserSurname)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserSurname)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserID)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserID)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
<p>

    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Bank")
</p>
```

Comment: This is great. It solves my problem. The only other thing I want to do it use a Button instead of an action result. Is this possible? Does the input of type submit accept parameters like the actionLink?

Comment: check my updated answer for that.  You can pass new parameter for css class

Comment: Perfect. All my problems have been solved. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

Can you please change your dataAnotation of ViewUser method from HttPost to HttpGet?
Because if you are trying to retrieve users doesnt make sense to have HttpPost there

So try to replace:

```
   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ViewUser(UserViewModel User)
        {

            string UserName = User.UserName;
            string UserSurname = User.UserSurname;

            return View(User);

        }
```

by this

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ViewUser(UserViewModel User)
        {

            string UserName = User.UserName;
            string UserSurname = User.UserSurname;

            return View(User);

        }
```